# How to install GDAL/scipy using cmd in window?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, gdal

I downloaded `scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` and `GDAL-1.11.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` from [gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) in **C:\Python27\Scripts**

To install I used

`pip install scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
 pip install GDAL-1.11.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`

It says the installation is complete but when I import the libraries as

```
import scipy
import gdal
```

it shows error as

> No module named gdal
>   No module named gdal

However, I installed the `matplotlib`, `numpy` in the very same way and they are working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem eventually to found the mistake in my approach. 
This problem can occur with anyone using ArcGIS in one's system.

ArcGIS comes with it's default Python package and if one installs python separately, each time the new libraries gets installed in the newer Python installation not in ArcGIS.

Therefore, the pyhton IDLE which one uses need to be from another Python installation. 
Here in my case, ArcGIS has Python 2.6 and I have made an separate installation using Python 2.7.11.

All the libraries were getting installed in right place but I was opening the wrong IDLE to write scripts hence getting error.